# Python - how to use read 'standard input' with called 'cat' command( bash) using fork execl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am very new to python. I am trying to simulate cat < file.txt in my python script but it is throwing an error.

```
import os, sys, time

f = open('file.txt' , "r")  # just hello world written in it. 

default_stdin = os.dup(sys.stdin.fileno())

os.dup2(f.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())

i = input()

print(i)  # so i is = 'hello world'

pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:

    os.execl('/bin/cat','cat', i )

    os.exit()

elif pid > 0:

    os.wait()

os.dup2(default_stdin, sys.stdin.fileno())

f.close()
```

I am passing the read output of input ('Hello world') and it is showing this error:

```
cat: 'Hello world.': No such file or directory
```

**I think it is because you have to provide a file name as an argument not a string. 
if that is the case how do i use the read standard input with cat command? (cat < file.txt)**

*very limited on resources, Cant use os.popen() or os.subprocess().*

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to simulate `cat` by calling `cat`?

Comment: Did you provide any command line arguments when running this script?

Comment: @dangee1705 They're trying to simulate `cat < file.txt` (which calls `cat`), not `cat`.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex yes, although they are doing this by calling `cat` in python, so I am wondering why they don't just use `cat`

Comment: wait, what the heck - you set up the input redirection and then *read the contents of the file to pass as a command line argument to `cat`*?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex how do you think it works? try it yourself. you will see this is how it works

Comment: @dangee1705 I think they're more trying to learn how to call other applications with their own provided `stdin` contents than to get a well-designed program out of the effort.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I think OP is trying to do something in a way which is far more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @dangee1705 It is more complicated than it needs to be to get the desired output, but it's a very simple way of learning to submit custom `stdin` contents to an application. It doesn't get much simpler than `cat`. You can see whether your efforts worked very quickly.

Comment: @dangee1705  hello, like Chai.T.Rex said I am not trying to make anything fancy , It is for an OS assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you're doing with `i` is wrong. After the first `dup2`, you've already set up input redirection. `cat` will read from `file.txt` as stdin and write its contents to stdout. You don't need to read the contents of the file yourself or pass any command line arguments.

Also, the `os.exit` is unreachable and unnecessary, since the `os.exec*` functions do not return.

Removing the `os.exit` and everything to do with `i` should produce a correct program:

```
import os, sys, time

f = open('file.txt', "r")
default_stdin = os.dup(sys.stdin.fileno())
os.dup2(f.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())

pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:
    os.execl('/bin/cat','cat')
elif pid > 0:
    os.wait()

os.dup2(default_stdin, sys.stdin.fileno())
f.close()
```

---

Incidentally, pretending you're the shell like this may be a good learning experience for, say, an OS class or something, but it's not a good idea for general programming. If you want to spawn a non-Python worker process, `subprocess.run` is usually the way to go. If you want to print the contents of a file, you can do it in Python with no subprocesses involved.

Comment: It is an for an OS assignment problem. Thanks heaps I got it now.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more, after redirecting standard input to a file if i call any command which takes input automatically starts taking inputs (without reading and giving it as an arguement like i did). Can it be thought as - I have already typed the input and cat is called so cat has all my input so it starts executing automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you want to use fork because if the aim is to replicate the behavior of `cat < file.txt` you don't need any.

It's maybe because of a little misunderstanding about how redirections do actually work. When you start a process - here `cat` - it has 3 file descriptors open:

- 0: the standard input
- 1: the standard output
- 2: the standard error output

The command `cat` only read the standard input and print it in the console (try to use cat without arguments in your terminal, it will stop only by pressing ^D which close the standard input). When you use the redirection in your terminal you only say that the file descriptor 0 is now pointing at your file.

So the valid code to reproduce the redirection into cat with python would just be

```
import os

fd = os.open("file.txt", os.O_RDONLY)
os.dup2(fd, 0)
os.execl('/bin/cat','cat')
```

Comment: That's enough to reproduce the redirection, but it destroys the current process instead of forking a worker, which is quite unlike how the shell handles `cat < file.txt`. Depending on whether the "fork a worker" behavior was also part of what we need to reproduce, this may not be enough.

Comment: Yes of course. But it's a little weird to avoid the overriding of the current process if it does nothing meanwhile. The shell do something like `read command; parse the command; fork; if I am the child exec the command and redirect streams if needed; wait; do it again` but it has nothing to do with the redirection and the child process is completely override by `cat`